# `TypeError: pool.getAll is not a function` when connecting to MongoDB

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express

I am writing an API with Node and Express, and use MongoDB as the database.

It has worked for a long time now, but today when I wrote some changes to a model, the server won't start anymore. I originally thought that a recent code change caused it, but even if I stash my changes and reset to a working state, the error occurs.

This is the error:

```
TypeError: pool.getAll is not a function
    at MongoCR.auth (/location/of/project/node_modules/mongodb/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/auth/mongocr.js:56:26)
    at Server.auth (/location/of/project/node_modules/mongodb/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/topologies/server.js:1019:40)
    at ReplSet.auth (/location/of/project/node_modules/mongodb/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/topologies/replset.js:572:17)
    at ReplSet.auth (/location/of/project/node_modules/mongodb/lib/replset.js:438:23)
    at authenticate (/location/of/project/node_modules/mongodb/lib/db.js:1319:21)
    at Db.authenticate (/location/of/project/node_modules/mongodb/lib/db.js:1356:44)
    at /location/of/project/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongo_client.js:414:25
    at /location/of/project/node_modules/mongodb/lib/db.js:221:5
    at connectHandler (/location/of/project/node_modules/mongodb/lib/replset.js:335:7)
    at g (events.js:260:16)
```

If I comment out all database connections the app runs. I've tried changing database, but it does not work either. I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32551798/node-js-and-mongodb-typeerror-undefined-is-not-a-function) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29451796/typeerror-object-is-not-a-function-in-using-mongodb-with-node-js) question and answer, and double checked versions and that all db-calls have callback-methods. I've used the last argument as the callback for calls that affect one entry, and `toArray(function(err, result){})` when there are multiple entries returned.

Mongo version is 2.6.3, and I use the [Node-mongodb driver](https://github.com/mongodb/node-mongodb-native).

I connect with

```
var mongo = require('mongodb').MongoClient;
var url = process.env.MONGODB || 'mongodb://localhost:27017/test';
var myCollection;
mongo.connect(url, function(err, db) {
    if(err) console.log(err);
    myCollection = db.collection('myCollection');
});
```

Then I have methods for e.g. find:

```
myCollection.find({}).toArray(function(err, result){
    // work with result    
});
```

I'm lost - thanks in advance.

Comment: The code provided by you works perfectly here.

Comment: Same here, are you sure the connection is not failing? You are not returning after the error logging, so this line `myCollection = db.collection('myCollection');` are being executed regardless if there was a connection error or not.

Comment: Apparently I've had at least three different database URL's wrong in a row over the course of three hours. I have no words. Thank you very much for your time!